# QED theta term as pullback of a volume form

Tags: topological-field-theory

The well-known QED theta term is

$S_\theta = \frac{\theta}{4\pi} \int d^4 x F \wedge F $

where $F=dA$ is the field strength 2-form. Altland and Simons (p.547) introduce a more general category of $\theta$ terms for situations where the 'target space', i.e. the space of all field configurations, is diffeomorphic to the spacetime manifold by $\phi : M \to T$,

$S_{top}[\phi] = i\theta \int_M \phi^* \omega$

where $\omega$ is the volume form on $T$, and $\phi^*$ is the pullback.

Can the QED theta term be written this way, or is the overlap in nomenclature a coincidence? Naively, I would have written down

$ \int A^* (da^0 \wedge da^1 \wedge da^2 \wedge da^3) $
which seems to have too many derivatives to possibly be correct.

Comment: What is $da^\mu$?

Comment: They're coordinates on some chart of $T$, the 3+1 dimensional space where values of A live.